# Iterating over object properties with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

here is my data structure:

```
$scope.table = {
                    a: ["1","2","3","4"],
                    b: ["5","6","7","8"]
               };
```

and i can loop through the keys with ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in table">
    <td>{{key}}</td> <!-- display a, b-->
    <td ng-repeat="???"></td>
</tr>
```

I also want to loop through the values array after the key, how should I continue?

Thank you!

Comment: yup I tried your way with a quick example on plunkr , but i still get a little bit of headache here. Can I chat with you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to loop over the array inside the properties, you can do the following:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.table = {
                    a: ["1","2","3","4"],
                    b: ["5","6","7","8"]
               };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, values) in table">
      <td ng-bind="key"></td>
      <td ng-repeat="value in values" ng-bind="value"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```